# Angular redundant databinding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new at my current company and refactoring code from my predecessor.

```
<th ng-repeat="(key,headline) in model.headlines" ng-class="headline.classes" data-ng-bind="headline.name">
    {{headline}}
</th>
```

I discovered that removing `{{headline}}` changes nothing (or adding anything e.g. text to the content of the object does nothing as well).

Removing the `data-ng-bind="headline.name"` and replacing `{{headline}}` with a `{{headline.name}}` enables me to add further content just like in any other html object.

As I'm new to angular and I deem my predecessor quite competent,
does the data-ng-bind="headline.name" have any benefits compared to the "inline-version" {{headline.name}}?

I want to add additional style to the object and putting another div into it would be great, but I can't do it with the data-ng-bind because it eats the content and just replaces it.

Could this change mess anything up ?

I'm quite confused why the more experienced predecessor would have written the code in a way that made it less agile in the first place, so I want to double check, that I'm not overlooking anything.

```
<th ng-repeat="(key,headline) in model.headlines" ng-class="headline.classes"">
    <div ng-class="additional styling">
        {{headline.name}}
    </div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

`{{...}}` has a bit of performance overhead on initialisation but in practice it's negligible. In practice the difference is that `ng-bind` will always replace the contents of the element where with `{{...}}` you're only setting a part of it so you can still append or prepend to the element.

In the end it's more preference than anything, I tend to use `ng-bind` if I know that's all I want as the content of the element.

Comment: The decreased readability of `ng-bind` in comparison to expression in element content IMO more than offsets the minuscule performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to bind the data to table header can you try to use this:

```
   <th ng-repeat="(key,headline) in model.headlines" ng-class="headline.classes"">
        <div ng-class="additional styling" data-ng-bind="headline.name">
        </div>
    </th>
```

Comment: yeah, but is the data-ng-bind="headline.name" better practice than the {{headline.name}} ? I've read somewhere that {{headline.name}} is the thing that you commonly use to bind data and seeing a bind written out is rather rare, but thanks for the suggestion, I haven't thought about moving the data-bind tag to the inner object

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-bind instead of the inplace {{...}} has one major benefit, which prevents the page to look like a hell of {{}} everywhere before angular kicks in and replaces everything (this can be very visible on slow devices (tablets, phones etc).

You can however get around it by adding ng-cloak class to the elements you don't want shown until angular is ready processing the template, then it will remove the ng-cloak and all will become visible.

(It happened to us when you switched to a page with some heavy charts and grids, it showed some really ugly {{}} all over the place on tablets).

Other then that the other answer about partial rendering and performance is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use the redundant way to provide debugging information.

In the first example in the question,
if the object has no headline.name property,
but an headline object, 
then the json object information is printed instead.

This can help to track down wheater the json object,
already exist and which properties have been set already,
this helps to track down where something might have gone wrong sometimes.